# How to play audio on xamarin android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

```html
public override void OnActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
 base.OnActivityCreated (savedInstanceState);
        StartMedia(source);
}
```

```
public void StartMedia(string url_string)
        {
            player = new MediaPlayer ();
            player.SetDataSource (url_string);
            //player.Prepare ();
            player.Start ();
        }
```

It don't run. don't run, don't listen anything. I have debug but I don't see it though over void StartMedia

```html
StartMedia(mListData[mPosition].stream_url+"?client_id="+clienId);

  }


  public async void StartMedia(string url_string)
  {
   player = new MediaPlayer ();
   player.SetVolume (100, 100);
   player.SetAudioStreamType (Stream.Music);
   await player.SetDataSourceAsync(Android.App.Application.Context,Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url_string));
   player.PrepareAsync ();
   player.Start ();
  

  }
```

When the audio to play is included as a resource, the method can be used to set up the data source to the audio file and prepare the player for playback automatically.

Comment: Change your `player.PrepareAsync ();` to `player.Prepare ();` since you are calling `Start` immediately after it, see my answer.

Answer (score 6):

1. Make sure you have a sub folder named raw under Resources.
2. Add the Audio file you need to play in raw folder.
   For example it is "MyAudio.mp3"

   ```
   MediaPlayer player;

   public bool StartMedia ()
   {
       player = MediaPlayer.Create (this, Resource.Raw.MyAudio);
       player.Start ();
       return true;
   }
   ```

[Reference](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/media/audio/play_audio/)

Comment: On simulator not so much; but, on the hardware it works great.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I use internet source...

#### Streaming Audio:

```
var mp3TestFile = "https://archive.org/download/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3";
player = new MediaPlayer();
player.SetAudioStreamType(Stream.Music);
await player.SetDataSourceAsync(ApplicationContext, Android.Net.Uri.Parse(mp3TestFile));
player.Prepare();
player.Start();
```

[Background Audio Streaming with Xamarin.Android](https://blog.xamarin.com/background-audio-streaming-with-xamarin-android/)

[image]

Comment: Don't run: On C# universal app :  if(Streamitem.stream_url!=null) 
                        { 
                            MediaPlayer.Source = new Uri(Streamitem.stream_url + "?client_id="+Api_key, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute); 
                             
                        }

Comment: @J.Joe Full `Xamarin.Android` code @ https://blog.xamarin.com/background-audio-streaming-with-xamarin-android/ @ https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/AndroidStreamingAudio/tree/master/Part%201%20-%20Simple%20Streaming

Comment: @J.Joe I update answer with a code snippet that contains a valid `.mp3` for testing